# Empty Value Bash

Tags: bash, macos, cname

I have a bash script as shown below

```sh
while read kk;
do 
    gname=$(host -t CNAME $kk | grep 'an alias' | awk '{print $NF}')
    if [ -n "$gname " ];
    then
        echo "Cname found is : $gname"
    fi
    echo "------------------------"
done
```

Even there is a value for gname I am getting an output as shown below

```sh
------------------------
Cname found is :
------------------------
Cname found is : example.routing.advocacytools.co
------------------------
Cname found is : api.example.com
```

Here for the firs line in the output , the variable cname is having an empty space or blank value but have an ip address , How can I filter out the output in such a way , if there is no cname value but only ip address the output should be

```sh
There is no cname , ip address is XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

OS : MacOSX

Comment: Note the trailing space inside ``"$gname "``. The length of ``"$gname "`` is *always* nonzero, even if ``$gname`` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of the space after `$gname` even if gname is empty the string between quotes contains a space and is not empty

compare

```
[ -n ' ' ] && echo ok
[ -n '' ] && echo ok
```